# When using OUTPUT in an insert statement, if you specify the order by in the select does it honor the order specified in the select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, output

I am inserting data into two tables.  Within each insert there is an OUTPUT to a #temp table each with an identity column.  The select that is generating the data for the insert has the same order by for each insert.  Later on I join the two #temp tables by the Identity column.  What I would expect is that the identity column numbers would line up as the order by is specified on both sides when inserting.  Every long once in a while it appears those numbers don't match up and the only thing I can think of is that perhaps the OUTPUT isn't always honoring the order by in the select statements when writing the OUTPUT data to the temp tables.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    RowNumber Integer IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    TableID Integer

    CONSTRAINT PK_TableID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (RowNumber)
)

INSERT INTO Table
    (column1,column2,column3,etc)
OUTPUT   
    INSERTED.ID
INTO #TempTable
    (ID)  
SELECT
    column1,column2,column3,etc
FROM
Other table
ORDER BY 
    SourceFlag,
    StoreID,
    storenumber,
    EstablishDate,
    TableID
```

What I would expect is that the statements would insert for example 25 rows in both statements in the same order 1 through 25.  Then I should be able to join based on the row number 1 = 1, 25= 25, etc. in order to get the matching data.  What I think is happening is somehow that order is getting messed up, so that row #1 from the first insert really matches say row #14 from the second, so when I later join 1 on 1 I'm getting mismatched data.

Comment: Your scenario is a bit unclear because the `INSERT` above should not work. `#TempTable` does not have an `ID`, while, if `#TempTable` does and it's an identity, inserting values to it won't work, unless you use `IDENTITY_INSERT`, which seems unnecessary. Rather than relying on any order of a generated identity, you could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY...)` to produce an explicit order.

Comment: Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql), "`INSERT` queries that use `SELECT` with `ORDER BY` to populate rows guarantees how identity values are computed *but not the order in which the rows are inserted*" (emphasis mine). Note that this only refers to the identity of the table being inserted to, not to any table referred in an `OUTPUT` clause -- what you get back from `INSERTED.ID` is deterministic, but the identity values generated as a result of `OUTPUT` will not be. But, per my earlier comment, you shouldn't need those.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, [it doesn't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql):

> However, SQL Server does not guarantee the order in which rows are
>   processed and returned by DML statements using the OUTPUT clause.

You need to identify a natural key in your data and then reference it to match the newly inserted rows with the `OUTPUT` resultset.

Alternatively, you can replace the `INSERT` with `MERGE`; in this case, you will be able to catch the newly created `identity` values for your records in the `OUTPUT` clause.